# Check whether variable has a value equal to some value in a fixed set

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, gurobi

I am currently modelling a linear program for which I am using a formulation which I do not know if it is good.
I have some variable X, and in some constraint I want to check if X takes on a value from some list or set (if this is the case, then the this value is forbidden, otherwise the constraint disabled via the BigM method etc etc, but I think this is not so important).
So as an example, SET = {1, 2, 10}, and now if in the solution X would be 2 this is not allowed, X has to take on a different value. 
Right now I am creating a constraint for every possible value x in SET and in the constraint use |X - x|, then do something like 0 <= |X - x| * BigM for every x.
Is there any "standard" way to model this, do you know a better solution? I did not find anything regarding this topic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

in OPL you could write

> {int} SET={1,2,10};
>
> dvar int x;
>
> subject to
>    {
>
> forall(i in SET) x!=i;
>
> }